# Unsupported charset with perforce plugin in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, perforce

I used perforce plugin in visual studio 2012. But after update the plugin with latest version, I got a message - "XXXXX(corrupted characters) or unsupported charset: utf8" when trying to connect to server.

Is there anything to try out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had just that issue today. My computer has had other users before me and it turned out that some Perforce environment variables were crappy. To check what variables you have on your system, just run *set* from the command line and look for variables starting with P4. I deleted all except the P4PORT, which I knew was ok.

How:

1. Right-click Computer, select Properties, then select advanced system settings on the left and click "Environment variables" at the bottom of the property dialog that opens (assuming you run Windows 7).
2. Delete any P4 system variable that you suspect of causing the problem (I took all but the P4Port and I see no immediate problems with it).
3. Close Visual Studio and reopen before trying again, so that it reloads all environment variables (and "forgets" the ones you deleted).

Note that if you want to recheck that the variables are gone, you need to close and open a new Command Prompt window too, because any open window/process remembers the state of the variables from when they first opened.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I've checked my environment variables and found out that 'P4CHARSET' is set to 'utf8'. I've removed this and got good working.